# PromQL: increase over counter

Tags: promql

Here my current counter value:

```
method_timed_seconds_count{method="getByUId"}  --->  68
```

After having fetch a http request to my service, this counter is iscremented:

```
method_timed_seconds_count{method="getByUId"}  --->  69
```

I want to get how this counter has increased inside a 30s window, using this:

```
increase(method_timed_seconds_count{method="getByUId"}[30s])  ---> 2
```

However, I'm getting value `2`!

Why? I was expecting to get `1`!

Scrape interval is `15s`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus has the following issues with `increase()` calculations:

- It extrapolates `increase()` results - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).
- It doesn't take into account the increase between the last raw sample before the specified lookbehind window in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window. See [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit) for details.
- It misses the increase for the first raw sample in a time series. For example, if a time series starts from `5` and has the following samples: `5 6 9 12`, then increase over these samples would return something around `12-5=7` instead of the expected `12`.

That's why it isn't recommended to use `increase()` in Prometheus for calculating the exact counter increases.

P.S. If you need calculating the exact counter increases over the specified lookbehind window, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It provides [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function, which is free from the issues mentioned above.