# PromQL increase() doesn't return correct counter increases

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have the following PromQL query

```
sum(endk_custom_label_total_count{BusinessProcess="acknowledgmentsent", Status="400"})
```

this gives the following result:
[image]

if I add a in increase to calculate the number of increases to the counter

```
sum(increase(endk_custom_label_total_count{BusinessProcess="acknowledgmentsent", Status="400"}[$__range]))
```

it returns `1`.
[image]

I expected this to return `3`.

I  tried adding `.. OR vector(0)` but it didn't change the outcome:

`sum(increase(endk_custom_label_total_count{BusinessProcess="acknowledgmentsent", Status="400"}[$__range])) OR vector(0)`

and

`sum(increase(endk_custom_label_total_count{BusinessProcess="acknowledgmentsent", Status="400"}[$__range]) OR vector(0))`

How do I make it calculate the correct increase?

*Update 1*

the raw metric looks look this:
[image]

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. sum(increase(metric)) is not the same as increase(sum(metric)). On your first graph if if you'll remove `sum` you'll see that metrics started in different times and one of them has changed from 1 to 2, and the other one was 1 all the time.

Comment: Regarding `or vector(0)`: AFAIK you cannot easily make Prometheus to assume metric was 0 for later use in the increase function (for good reason). This can be done with some `offset`, `or` and subquery trickery, but you should ask yourself first if that what is needed here.

Comment: hi @markalex, thx for the reply.
I don't understand yout first comment

Comment: Your current result of 1 is because your metrics have increased by 1 and 0 accordingly. Prometheus doesn't implicitly consider metrics to be 0 if they are missing (unless it's a reset). And theoretically with your initial screen it could be even 0 if you'd have three metrics started at 09:05, 09:08 and 09:13 all with constant value of 1.

Comment: we are switching to Victoria Metrics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74126079/1244816